# Initial Value of Select2Multiple widget

Tags: jquery, django, django-autocomplete-light

I am working on a searchinput with additional parameters given through a django autocomplete light Select2Multiple widget.

```
class SearchParameterForm(forms.Form):
    p = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=autocomplete.Select2Multiple(url='search-parameter-autocomplete'),
        label='Search Parameter',
        required=False,
    )
```

&

```
class SearchParameterAutocomplete(LoginRequiredMixin, autocomplete.Select2ListView):
    def get_list(self):
        parameter_list = ['only stocked']
        for my_storage in Storage.objects.filter(workgroup=self.request.user.profile.workgroup).all():
            for workgroup in my_storage.workgroup.all():
                parameter_list.append(workgroup.name)
        return list(set(parameter_list))
```

I would like to set the initial value of the Widget depending on some parameters (e.g. `self.request.user.profile.workgroup.name`)

Setting the initial value of the field either directly in the class with some dummy values or in the view did not work. I would also like to store the selected values on page refresh.

```
initial = {"id": "AK2", "text": "AK2"}
initial = ['AK1']
initial = 'AK1'
```

Is there a way to do this with django or jquery?

~Fabian